# Equals doesn't work on structs?

Tags: c#, .net

For extremely horrible reasons, I have this struct in my employers application.

I tried to override the equality operator, but I get error `Error   9   Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TR_St_DateTime' and 'TR_St_DateTime'`
.

What am I missing?

```
public struct TR_St_DateTime : IEquatable<TR_St_DateTime>
{
    public int Year;
    public int Month;
    public int Day;
    public int Hour;
    public int Minute;
    public int Second;

    public TR_St_DateTime(DateTime time)
    {
        Day = time.Day;
        Hour = time.Hour;
        Minute = time.Minute;
        Second = time.Second;
        Month = time.Month;
        Year = time.Year;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        TR_St_DateTime o = (TR_St_DateTime) obj;
        return Equals(o);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Year ^ Month ^ Day ^ Hour ^ Minute ^ Second;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", Day, Month, Year);
    }

    public bool Equals(TR_St_DateTime other)
    {
        return ((Day == other.Day) && (Month == other.Month) && (Year == other.Year) && (Minute == other.Minute) && (Hour == other.Hour) && (Second == other.Second));
    }
}
```

UPDATE: 
It seems that `==` doesn't work but `Equals` does.

There is no need to implement `Equals` on structs.

Comment: What't the exact error?

Comment: Error 9 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TR_St_DateTime' and 'TR_St_DateTime'

Comment: Operator == is not the same as the method Equals, and indeed often gives a different result.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: No, the `Equals(object)` method *has* been overridden. It's been overloaded as well, that's all.

Comment: @JonSkeet, ah, I didn't see the first implementation. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't overloaded the `==` operator, which is why the compiler's complaining. You just need to write:

```
public static bool operator ==(TR_St_DateTime left, TR_St_DateTime right)
{
    return left.Equals(right);
}

public static bool operator !=(TR_St_DateTime left, TR_St_DateTime right)
{
    return !(left == right);
}
```

I would *strongly* recommend that you avoid those public fields though. Mutable structs can cause any number of unintended side-effects unless you're careful.

(You should also follow .NET naming conventions, and return `false` if the `Equals(object)` method is called with a reference to an instance of a different type, rather than unconditionally casting.)

Comment: @NahumLitvin - Except `The Master` is crazy and John isn't crazy. **Yes I made a `Doctor Who` reference**

Comment: I learn something every time I read one of your answers. For more than a decade I've always done stuff like implement equality interfaces or override `Equals` - but I believe I'll be building my own `==` and `!=` operators now! **One question,** is this actually more performant than say the equality interfaces and such?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: Implementing `IEquatable<T>` would allow things like `HashSet<T>` to be more efficient by avoiding boxing - but if you can avoid a virtual call entirely, that will be more efficient too. Using `==` wouldn't be any faster than calling `Equals(TR_St_DateTime)` directly though.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks a lot for helping me get a better understanding!

Answer (score 3):

Overriding the `Equals` method doesn't automatically implement `==` as well.  You still need to manually overload those operators and feed them to the `Equals` method

```
public static bool operator==(TR_St_DateTime left, TR_St_DateTime right) {
  return left.Equals(right);
}

public static bool operator!=(TR_St_DateTime left, TR_St_DateTime right) {
  return !left.Equals(right);
}
```

Comment: john beated you by a few seconds :)

Comment: @NahumLitvin if you look at the time stamps, I beat him :)